# Measurability of an Indicator Function

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

I am aware of an indicator function is measurable iff its indicator set is measurable. However, I am unsure if the following indicator function is actually measurable: Define $f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as $f(x, y) = \mathbb{1}_{(-\infty, x]}(y)$. I am trying to show this function as Borel measurable and the following is what I have tried so far:

For $\alpha \geq 1$, $f^{-1}((\alpha, \infty)) = \emptyset$, which is measurable. For $\alpha < 0$, $f^{-1}((\alpha, \infty)) = \mathbb{R}^2$. For $0 \leq \alpha < 1$, I am unsure how to find the preimage $f^{-1}((\alpha, \infty)) = f^{-1}(\{ 1 \})$. How does one see this as measurable?

Comment: $f^{-1}(\{1\})=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: y\leq x\}$ is a closed set in $\mathbb R^2$, hence measurable.

Comment: $1_{(-\infty,x]}(y) = 1_A(x,y)$, where $A= \{ (x,y) \mid y \le x \}$. Since $A$ is closed it is measurable.

Comment: I guess you meant measurable set on the first sentence ?